# How can cash out your bitcoin wallet

Tags: transactions

can you cash out your bitcoin wallet and how do you receive the money from your wallet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to convert your bitcoin into a fiat currency, like the US dollar for example, you would need to have an account on an exchange, then send the bitcoin you want to cash out to the address associated with that account. After that, you would sell the bitcoin into US dollars and follow the instructions from the exchange for how to receive the money in a regular bank account. Most of the time I think they wire it. The process might be different in different countries and for different exchanges.